# Force file download of unknown file type with PHP

Tags: php

I am looking to force the download of a file from an external source using PHP headers. However, the file type could be **ANYTHING**. **How can I force the download of all file types**?

I hope you can understand my question and what I am trying to describe.

Comment: Forcing all downloads seems like a bad idea to me...

Comment: Look at the PHP documentation for `readfile()`, specifically setting the headers to octet-stream.

Comment: agree with @Jon, it's a bad UX decision. are you 100% sure your users want to download the file? are you 100% sure they want to save it in their default download directory, with the default name? IFF you can say yes to these, then proceed.

Comment: by default name i mean the name of the file on the server. i'm not saying that there is no acceptable use for this, im just saying use it judiciously

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean HTTP headers, and you're looking for RFC 2616, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html "Content Disposition".

Send the following headers to force a download of ALL files and types:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="name.ext"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); // or application/force-download

echo $the_file_content;
exit;
```

Comment: If you mean the MIME-type, `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Oh, it's specific. It declares that your file consists of bytes. If your file does not consist of bytes, you'll have to find something else.

Comment: @CosmoPosmo, what file type can you possibly be thinking of that DOESN'T consist of bytes?